# Why is the carbon-fluorine bond stronger than the other haloalkanes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides

What effect makes  C-F bond  stronger than  other halo-alkanes?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21581

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a carbon-fluorine bond stronger than a carbon-chlorine bond?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21581/is-a-carbon-fluorine-bond-stronger-than-a-carbon-chlorine-bond)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [wikipedia article of carbon-fluorine bond,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon%E2%80%93fluorine_bond)

> The high electronegativity of fluorine (4.0 for F vs. 2.5 for carbon)
>   gives the carbon–fluorine bond a significant polarity/dipole moment.
>   The electron density is concentrated around the fluorine, leaving the
>   carbon relatively electron poor. This introduces ionic character to
>   the bond through partial charges ($\ce{C^{δ+}—F^{δ−}}$). **The partial
>   charges on the fluorine and carbon are attractive, contributing to the
>   unusual bond strength of the carbon–fluorine bond.** The bond is
>   labeled as "**the strongest in organic chemistry,"** because fluorine
>   forms the strongest single bond to carbon. Carbon–fluorine bonds can
>   have a bond dissociation energy (BDE) of up to 544 kJ/mol. (This is why) The BDE
>   (strength of the bond) is higher than other carbon–halogen and
>   carbon–hydrogen bonds. For example, the molecule represented by
>   $\ce{CH3X}$ has a BDE of 115 kcal/mol for carbon–fluorine while values
>   of 104.9, 83.7, 72.1, and 57.6 kcal/mol represent $\ce{C–X}$ bonds
>   to hydrogen, chlorine, bromine, and iodine, respectively.